# DL4J example on GPU doesn't work (for a school project)

Tags: java, gpu, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I already have experience with deep learning. I use python and cuda works fine with my GPU when training a model. BUT, now I need to use Java *(for an optional school project I want to create a reinforcement learning AI and I have to use Java)*. I'm completely new to Java so I followed [this video](https://youtu.be/N5sQcOOtehY) which is based on the quickstart guide of the DL4J website. When it comes to dowloading the examples, everything works fine : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhAkn.png).

When I run examples on cpu (with neural nets) everythings works fine. But, when I try this one "MultiGpuLenetMnistExample" *(it's in the "dl4j-cuda-specific-examples" folder)*, I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9vsK.png) and I tried to look for answers but I didn't find what I wanted (or maybe didn't understand the answers). I guess the problem comes from the nd4j backend or something with jcublas but I don't know what to do with that.

Consider that I am not comfortable yet with all the subtilities of Java, when I looked for people with the same issue I didn't understand what they were talking about, I just discovered the concept of pom.xml files for example... But I've seen that people answering were usualy asking for the java -version, mvn --version or nvcc --version so [here they are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNy0G.png).

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshots, you're trying to run project with deps for CUDA 10.2, but you have CUDA 10.0 installed. Change your dependency to nd4j-cuda-10.0 instead of nd4j-cuda-10.2

Comment: I chnaged that <name>DeepLearning4j CUDA special examples</name>
    <properties>
      <nd4j.backend>nd4j-cuda-10.2-platform</nd4j.backend>
    </properties> int this <name>DeepLearning4j CUDA special examples</name>
    <properties>
      <nd4j.backend>nd4j-cuda-10.0-platform</nd4j.backend>
    </properties>

Comment: And in the dependencies (in the pom file) they used cuda 9.2, 10.0, 10.1 and 10.2 so I removed 9.2, 10.1 and 10.2 but it still doesnt work

Comment: That's not how you specify a dependency in a POM file, search "specifying dependencies in Maven"

Comment: It works ! It runs and I get the confusion matrix and all ... but i get this message in the initialization "cuDNN not found: use cuDNN for better GPU performance by including the deeplearning4j-cuda module. For more information, please refer to: [link](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-config-cudnn)" I don't understand because I did what they say in the link but I still get this "cuDNN not found" message

Comment: That's just a hint. If you have cuDNN installed, you can add "deeplearning4j-cuda-10.x" dependency, and improve performance of selected ops supported by cuDNN.

Comment: @raver119 I've seen your name in lots of dl4j projects (especially this "MultiGpuLenetMnistExample") thanks for all your work ^^ ! I think I'm pretty close to get it done I just have this kind of [error](https://snipboard.io/baLuwS.jpg) messages when running the program (in the long line the message in french says "The specified procedure could not be found").

Comment: And also it's strange because when I do nvcc --version it tells me I have cuda 10.0 and with nvidia-smi it tells me I have 10.1 ... And I tried with both dependecies and I get the same error (in the last link)

Comment: You either have multiple CUDA versions installed, or that's just driver reporting wrong version. In any way - that's pure versions clash, and the real way to get it fixed - to sort out what you actually have installed

Comment: Message you've posted above is exactly it - you have multiple versions of CUDA-related stuff installed, but it's binary incompatible. I.e. cuDNN for 10.0 isn't compatible with CUDA 10.2